# bitcoind synced more blocks than in the blockchain?

Tags: bitcoind

I just installed bitcoind on a fresh Ubuntu server and synced.

However, it seemingly have synced more blocks than there are in the blockchain!

```
$ bitcoind getblockcount
309905
$ curl http://blockexplorer.com/testnet/q/getblockcount
26787
```

How is that possible?

Is there something wrong with my installation?
Do I have to remove it all and restart from scratch?

Here is my bitcoind config:

```
#testnet=1
server=1
#daemon=1
rpcuser=[redacted]
rpcpassword=[redacted]
rpctimeout=30
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
rpcport=19332


addnode=95.85.39.28:18333
addnode=46.4.106.234:18333
addnode=94.102.53.181:18333
addnode=5.135.159.139:18333
addnode=188.226.138.211:18333
addnode=188.165.238.173:18333
addnode=46.28.204.15:18333
addnode=109.201.135.216:18333
addnode=5.9.2.145:18333
addnode=46.182.106.2:18333
addnode=109.201.154.201:18333
addnode=188.165.246.217:18333
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You requested the amount of blocks in the testnet. In the 'real' blockchain, there are currently 309913 blocks, which is in agreement with your blockcount.

Change

```
$ curl http://blockexplorer.com/testnet/q/getblockcount
```

into

```
$ curl http://blockexplorer.com/q/getblockcount
```

So no need of removal of anything. Everything is perfectly fine.